# Logical 'or' symbol | in Libreoffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice

I am working on a docx file in Libreoffice Writer, and I have a formula that contains a vertical line such as `x | y`. My source code in the formula editor is "x divides y". However, when I save the document and re-open it, the formula appears as `x v y`, and the source code has changed to "x | y".

I guess working in odt format would solve this particular problem. However, when I save my document as odt now, the formatting of the whole document will screw up so much that this is not an option.

How can I write this symbol "|" in a way that it works in both formats?

Answer (score 0):

For that particular symbol try this formula:

```
left none x mline y right none
```